# Disk Arbitration and OK button issue

Tags: macos, cocoa, diskarbitration

The code below is used to get the list of disks

```
(void)da_tools
{
    DASessionRef session;

    session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback(session, NULL, disk_appeared_callback, (void *)NULL);
    DASessionScheduleWithRunLoop(session, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    CFRunLoopRun();
    CFRelease(session);
}
```

The IBAction for the OK button is: `[self da_tools]`;

The callback function *disk_appeared_callback* works perfectly and give the right information.

The problem happens at *CFRunLoopRun()* when the OK button is hit:

- the *CFRunLoopRun()* take many seconds to execute or never end.
- The callback function disk_appeared_callback itself is executed in milli-seconds time.

However any key press to the keyboard (or a mouse click everywhere (and sometime just a mouse move))
force *CFRunLoopRun()* to exit and the callback function *disk_appeared_callback* is promptly executed.

When *CFRunLoopRun()* is removed `da_tools` does not return any disk information at the first OK button hit
but subsequent OK button hit returns the correct disk information.

I have tried to include `da_tools` in an another thread:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(da_tools) toTarget:self withObject:nil]
```

but this doesn't help.

I also tried to post a keydown event but this fails too.

How to use *CFRunLoopRun* correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Please do not to use call `CFRunLoopRun();` method separately and please not release session `CFRelease(session);` because you will not received any callback later on.

---

**How to established session with DiskArbitration and listen via callbacks?**

Creating DA session and schedule session run loop:

```
// Disk Arbitration Session
DASessionRef session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
if (!session) {
    [NSException raise:NSGenericException format:@"Unable to create Disk Arbitration session."];
    return;
}

NSLog(@"Disk Arbitration Session created");

// schedule DA session run loop
DASessionScheduleWithRunLoop(session, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
```

If you like to listen for all disk events including internal one. Then Pass `NULL` while registering callbacks.

Else create a `matching condition` for your callbacks. For example: following condition for external hard disk, memory disk connects via USB.

```
// Matching Conditions
CFMutableDictionaryRef match = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

// Device matching criteria
// 1. Of-course it shouldn't be internal device since
CFDictionaryAddValue(match, kDADiskDescriptionDeviceInternalKey, kCFBooleanFalse);

// Volume matching criteria
// It should statisfy following
CFDictionaryAddValue(match, kDADiskDescriptionVolumeMountableKey, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFDictionaryAddValue(match, kDADiskDescriptionVolumeNetworkKey, kCFBooleanFalse);
```

Look at `DADisk.h`, we add more conditions for your need.

Registering Callbacks with DiskArbitration, more info on callbacks [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DiskArbitration/Reference/DiskArbitration_header_reference/index.html)-

```
NSString * const AppName = @"DAApp";

// Registring callbacks
DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback(session, match, DiskAppearedCallback, (__bridge void *)AppName);
DARegisterDiskDisappearedCallback(session, match, DiskDisappearedCallback, (__bridge void *)AppName);
DARegisterDiskDescriptionChangedCallback(session, match, NULL, DiskDescriptionChangedCallback, (__bridge void *)AppName);

// And now release match
CFRelease(match);
```

... Application things goes around...**

Finally Unregister and release everything. Typical place is application terminate or dealloc.

```
// DA Session
if (session) {
    DAUnregisterCallback(session, DiskAppearedCallback, (__bridge void *)AppName);
    DAUnregisterCallback(session, DiskDisappearedCallback, (__bridge void *)AppName);

    DASessionUnscheduleFromRunLoop(session, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CFRelease(session);

    NSLog(@"Disk Arbitration Session destoryed");
}
```

I hope it helps!

---

BTW, for DA Approval Session like this

```
// Disk Arbitration Approval Session
DASessionRef approvalSession = DAApprovalSessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
if (!approvalSession) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to create Disk Arbitration approval session.");
    return;
}

NSLog(@"Disk Arbitration Approval Session created");
DAApprovalSessionScheduleWithRunLoop(approvalSession, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

// Same match condition for Approval session too
DARegisterDiskMountApprovalCallback(approvalSession, match, DiskMountApprovalCallback, (__bridge void *)AppName);

// may need CFRelease(match); based code sequence!
```

Finally unregister and release.

```
// DA Approval Session
if (approvalSession) {
    DAUnregisterApprovalCallback(approvalSession, DiskMountApprovalCallback, (__bridge void *)AppName);

    DAApprovalSessionUnscheduleFromRunLoop(approvalSession, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CFRelease(approvalSession);

    NSLog(@"Disk Arbitration Approval Session destoryed");
}
```

For more info on above code snippets [here](https://github.com/jeevatkm/NTFS-OSX/blob/master/NTFS-OSX/Arbitration.m).